# rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg FAILED.. Please help

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam_freiburg']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/hasitha/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131028-235835
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam_freiburg'] to: ['rgbdslam']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> octomap_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< octomap_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_ros
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nav_msgs No Makefile in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> flann [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mk [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> arm_navigation_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mk No Makefile in package mk
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv_tests ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< arm_navigation_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package arm_navigation_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> octomap_server [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< octomap_server ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_server
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers
[ rosmake ] All 2 linesrgbdslam: 0.0 sec ] [ 1 Active 47/48 Complete ] {------------------------------------------------------------------------------- mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to: [ rosmake ] /home/hasitha/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131028-235835/rgbdslam/build_output.log [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 0.07 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam. [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 48 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/hasitha/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131028-235835

Permission denied when i use rosmake command

plzzzzzzzzzzzzz help on this ...!!!!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172426/rosmake-rgbdslam_freiburg-failed..-please-help/) by [mohsin ali](https://answers.ros.org/users/18201/mohsin-ali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While both is possible, it's definitely better to work in a directory in your home and add it to the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable, than to develop/build as superuser.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1